# How to get other column records with the ID in SQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm new to mySQL coding and figuring out on my own.

I'm trying to get employee data(Name, dob, etc) using manager ID. So I have the manager table with all the manager information like managerID, name, dob, salary etc and an employee table with emp info like empID, name, salary, dob and managerID. So if I want to get the emp details using the managerID how can I do it in mysql?

Manager

```
CREATE TABLE manager
(managerid      CHAR(4)     NOT NULL,
mfname      VARCHAR(15)     NOT NULL,
mlname      VARCHAR(15)     NOT NULL,
mbdate      DATE        NOT NULL,
msalary     NUMERIC(9,2)    NOT NULL,
mbonus      NUMERIC(9,2),
mresbuildingid  CHAR(3),        
PRIMARY KEY (managerid) );
```

#### EMPLOYEE

```
CREATE TABLE employee
(empid      CHAR(3)     NOT NULL,
efname      VARCHAR(15)     NOT NULL,
elname      VARCHAR(15)     NOT NULL,
ebdate      DATE        NOT NULL,
esalary     NUMERIC(9,2)    NOT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY (empid),
FOREIGN KEY (buildingid) REFERENCES building(buildingid),
FOREIGN KEY (ccid) REFERENCES corpclient(ccid) )
FOREIGN KEY (managerid) REFERENCES Manager(managerid);\
```

#### BUILDING

```
CREATE TABLE building
(   buildingid  CHAR(3)     NOT NULL,
bmlocation CHAR NOT NULL,
bmanagerid      CHAR(4)     NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (buildingid),
FOREIGN KEY (bmanagerid) REFERENCES manager(managerid) );
```

Comment: please share your table structure and relations between them.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to select by it:

`SELECT * FROM employee WHERE managerid = 1`

Comment: Yep, I got that part. 

So I have another table called building which has buildingID, location and managerID. This shows where the manager is located. 

And I have query like what is the location of the manager who has most number of emp under him/her. how can I code that? Like, the emp table have both the manager id and the building id.